# Understanding what a question is asking

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $g_x=f_x-f_a$, where a is fixed and $f_x(y)=d(x,y)$. Show that the map $x\mapsto g_x$ is a distance preserving embedding of X into the normed space of bounded functions on X.

When the question say show the map $x\mapsto g_x$ is distant preserving, does that mean I need to show for all $y,z\in X$ , we have $d(z,y)=d(g_x(z),g_x(y))$? And when it says that show the function is bounded in a normed space, do I show there exists $M>0$ such that $||g_x||\leq M$ or $|g_x(y)|\leq M$?

Thanks for your help to understand this question.

Comment: No, distance-preserving would be $d(x,y)=\|g_x-g_y\|=\sup_{z\in X}|g_x(z)-g_y(z)|$.

Comment: It does not say that *the function is bounded in a normed space*. It is referring to *the normed space of bounded functions on* $X$, which is the normed space $(B(X),\lVert \bullet\rVert_\infty)$, where $$B(X)=\{f:X\to\Bbb R\,\mid\, \sup_{x\in X}\lvert f(x)\rvert<\infty\}\\ \lVert f\rVert_\infty=\sup_{x\in X}\lvert f(x)\rvert$$ (the assumption/convention is that $B(\varnothing)$ is the zero vector space with the constant zero norm).

Comment: To show that $g_x$ is indeed bounded, you can show either one $\|g_x\|\leq M$ or for all $y\in X,\ |g_x(y)|\leq M$. Observe that $|g_x(y)|=|d(x,y)-d(a,y)|\leq d(a,x)$, by triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks! just to make sure I understand it now. So I should first prove the equality mentioned by @user85667 to show $g_x$ is distant preserving and then show $g_x\in B(X)$ by showing it is bounded. Just making sense out of it, distant preserving means the distance between images of distinct points is the same as the distance between the preimages of these points, and so we want $d(x,y)=||g_x-g_y||$ instead of what I said is because we are looking at this map $x\mapsto g_x$ instead of the map $g_x:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?